# Trouble accessing functions of NetAPI32 wrapped in WCF that create users

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5, com, netapi32

I have created a project which is basically described as a consumable service to create or edit users on a remote computer. The idea is to connect to a server and add a user. The structure of the project is as follows:

- WCF Service: to expose functions to create/edit/select users
- Utility assembly: Netapi32 COM functions wrapped in a utility class
- Consumer: Usable assembly that wraps calls to the WCF service to use in site

The problem I am having, is that I can get a list of all the users on the computer running the WCF service, but i cannot create or edit them. it is only giving me readonly functionality.

Does anyone have any idea how I might be able to fix this or even trouble shoot it?

Answer (score 0):

The account that actually runs the WCF Service may very well not have rights to create or edit users.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your service is running under an admin user that actually has the rights to create users. If you use the default user for IIS i bet it does not have that kind of access.